# Numeric calculations using dplyr piping commands

Tags: r, dplyr, numeric, piping

Is it possible to use piping from the dplyr package to do numeric calculations? A simple example is:

```
    0.15 %>% 3.8416 * (.*(1-.))/(0.03^2)  #does not work
    seq(1,10,1) %>% log(.) %>% .^2        #works
```

Tying to understand more of how piping works and when it can and cannot be used. I really enjoy using the piping feature and want to find a way to use it for these types of numeric calculations.

Many thanks

Comment: Piping is from the `magrittr` package, not the `dplyr` package. I'd suggest having a look at [the readme](https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr).

Comment: But also, use a pipe to make things clearer and more readable. That's what it's for. Your first example makes things more difficult to read.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification on which package the piping comes from and  I do agree with Gregor that the piping should always be used to make things easier to read

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an operator precedence problem. It's trying to start by doing

```
0.15 %>% 3.8416
```

which doesn't make sense. You need to group all your calculations in a code block

```
0.15 %>% {3.8416 * (.*(1-.))/(0.03^2)}
```

Comment: This is was I was looking for. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 3):

All of these are equivalent, you'll need `magrittr` for the first one, `dplyr` is enough for the next 2:

```
library(magrittr)
0.15 %>% multiply_by(subtract(1,.)) %>% multiply_by(3.8416) %>% divide_by(0.03^2)
0.15 %>% `*`(`-`(1,.)) %>% `*`(3.8416) %>% `/`(0.03^2)
0.15 %>% {3.8416 * (.*(1-.))/(0.03^2)}
```

Comment: Thank you for demonstrating the flexibility of the piping commands to conduct numeric analysis when we desire to pass through either the data or  the calculation command (i.e. division, multiplication, etc.)