# How to feed pipe into an inequality?

Tags: r, piping, magrittr

This has come up in multiple instances, and I do not know if this current instance is generalizable to the many cases where this arises for me, but I'm hoping an answer may shed some light.

The simplest version of this is when I am doing some data processing and want to perform an evaluation on the result of a pipe. A simple example would be:

```
> seq(9) %>% > 4
Error: unexpected '>' in "seq(9) %>% >"
> seq(9) %>% . > 4
Error in .(.) : could not find function "."
```

The desired output would be a logical vector

```
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

In many circumstances I want to evaluate on some piped output but have to assign it and then perform the evaluation for it to work:

```
seq(9) -> vec
vec > 4
```

Is there a way to complete these sorts of evaluations within a pipe chain entirely?

Comment: `sapply` is unnecessary, `>` is vectorized

Comment: @BenBolker Oh right, good call.

Comment: Some very related questions, might be good to create an R-FAQ: [Numeric calculations using `dplyr`'s piping command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46836185/903061), [Order of operations with piping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38531508/903061). I know I've seen others too. They don't quite seem like duplicates, but a canonical duplicate could probably be constructed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use curly braces if you just want to use pipes.

```
seq(9) %>% {. > 4}

[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

I'd recommend using `purrr` if you're going to be piping these kinds of things, as it will result in a bit more readable code.

```
library(purrr)

map_lgl(seq(9), ~.x > 4)

[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: I know it's a weird example, but it is a little laughable to describe `map_lgl(seq(9), ~.x > 4)` as "more readable" than the unpiped alternative, `seq(9) > 4`.

Comment: I see your point, but I meant in the context of a longer chain of code.  I just find the use of braces in the middle of a chain a bit jarring.

Answer (score 5):

One more option is to call the `>` function as a function rather than an operator:

```
> seq(9) %>% `>`(4)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
> seq(9) %>% '>'(4)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

I think the backquotes make the most sense, but regular quotes do work in this case as well.

Answer (score 4):

`magrittr` provides "aliases" to turn binary operators into pipe-able functions. I don't care for them myself, but you can do

```
library(magrittr)
seq(9) %>% is_greater_than(4)
```

See the full list at `?add` (which is an alias for `+`). There are implementations for everything from `+` to `[[`.

Answer (score 2):

In a slightly broader context, this is easily done with `mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)
data_frame(x=1:9) %>% mutate(big_x = x>4)
```

**Unsolicited opinion**: If you're mostly working with atomic vectors, I suspect that the tidyverse/piping approach is going to be more trouble than it's worth. As the other answer suggests, you can use `purrr`, but again, base R may work perfectly well. More context for your problem might help.

Comment: My work are very often are actually matrices and as far as I can tell I can't use dplyr commands (ie mutate, etc) without converting into a data frame. I had searched for a way but it doesn't appear that functionality exists without converting into a data frame.